# DELPHI Table cell split & merge

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

How can I make something like this in Delphi:

[image: Table]

I know I can make it from 3 tables so it would be easier, but how can I make Table cells split & merge and how to get the text to turn 90deg.?

Is there some good content libraries that have split & merge built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `woll2woll` or `infopower`.  They will do the grid for sure.  The font can be achieved by overriding the `OnDrawDataCell`, `OnDrawGroupHeaderCell` and `OnDrawTitleCell` events and writing the text with rotated font.

```
{****************************************************************
* Create angled font. Procedure writen by Keith Wood            *
****************************************************************}
procedure CreateAngledFont (AFont : TFont; const AAngle : Integer);
var
  FntLogRec: TLogFont { Storage area for font information } ;
begin
  { Get the current font information. We only want to modify the angle }
  fillchar (FntLogRec, sizeof(FntLogRec), #0);
  GetObject (AFont.Handle, SizeOf(FntLogRec), Addr(FntLogRec));

  { Modify the angle. "The angle, in tenths of a degrees, between the   base
    line of a character and the x-axis." (Windows API Help file.) }
  FntLogRec.lfEscapement   := (AAngle * 10);
  FntLogRec.lfOrientation  := (AAngle * 10);
  FntLogRec.lfOutPrecision := OUT_TT_PRECIS;  { Request TrueType precision }

  { Delphi will handle the deallocation of the old font handle }
  AFont.Handle := CreateFontIndirect (FntLogRec);
end;
```